# Angular : loop over object data loaded from a webservice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm loading data form an external webservice.
*My code looks like this :*

**My Service ( to load restfull data):**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  loadDataItems(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(data => {
        data.json();
        return data.json();
      });
  }
}
```

**My Component (where am injecting my previous service to display data):**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import {HttpService} from '../http.service';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  dataItems: any;
  nb = 0;
  private dataUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/list';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private dataServer: HttpService ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataServer.loadDataItems(this.dataUrl).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataItems = data;
        console.log(this.dataItems);
      }
    );
    for (let i = 0 ; i < this.dataItems.length ; i++) {
      if (this.dataItems.g = 'chrome') {
        this.nb++
      }
    }

    // Build the chart
      Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
        chart: {
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Brands',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33
          }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
          }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38
          }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77
          }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91
          }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2
          }]
        }]
      });
  }
}
```

My purpose is to loop of the items of my received object data , where i need to count data with specific attribute :

```
  if (this.dataItems.g = 'chrome')
```

But i got an error indicating that this is not defined :

> this.dataItems.length

i won't filter it with **ngFor** and **ngIf** , because i wanna catch the counted value in the **ts** *file* , to use it in the **highchart** widget composant .

**Any ideas ??**

Comment: Hi, and what console.log(this.dataItems); return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For count or filter you can just use filter...
Long time no see so syntax may be wrong...

```
       var query = myArray.filter(
                       function(element){
                          return element.propert == neededValue && 
                                 element.property == otherValue;
                       }
                   );

       return query?query.length:0;
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

`this.dataServer.loadDataItems` is async function, it doesn't return the result immediately. You should loop over loaded object into `subscribe` function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataServer.loadDataItems(this.dataUrl).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataItems = data;
        console.log(this.dataItems);
        for (let i = 0 ; i < this.dataItems.length ; i++) {
          if (this.dataItems.g = 'chrome') {
            this.nb++
          }
        }
    });
}
```

Also, you have a bug in `if` condition. You should use there `===` operator instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  loadDataItems(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(data => data.json());
  }
}


import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import {HttpService} from '../http.service';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  dataItems: any;
  nb = 0;
  private dataUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/list';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private dataServer: HttpService ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataServer.loadDataItems(this.dataUrl).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataItems = data;

        for (let i = 0 ; i < this.dataItems.length ; i++) {
            if (this.dataItems.g == 'chrome') {
                this.nb++
            }
        }
        console.log(this.dataItems);
      }
    );

    // Build the chart
      Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
        chart: {
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Brands',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33
          }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
          }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38
          }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77
          }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91
          }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2
          }]
        }]
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop object like an array

```
let yourObject = {
   name: "firas",
   age: "20"
}

Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(key => {
    let valueFromObject = yourObject[key]   // firas
})
```

and care about

```
 if (this.dataItems.g = 'chrome') {   --> = change to ==
        this.nb++
 }
```